# Multiple items sencha carousel

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, carousel, sencha-touch-2

**Hi,**

I could not manage to get where i want with my carousel. This is for an iPhone / iPad web App.

Basically i **want to show part of my previous and next item card** inside the carousel. Because a picture is worth a thousand words here is the final view i want to obtain :

[image: final]

Same as in the appStore preview screenshots of an app.

I have tried many things but nothing have work so far.

Any tips would be great :) Thank you !

Comment: :Hi,Did you get any solution that works good in both iphone and android?thanks!!

Comment: Nha i ended with a simple carrousel sadly. i am very disapointed with sencha and i am now back on native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would definitely be possible, if you were to 'push' the carousel pages 3 onto one page, with spacing (margin or padding) up high to create the effect.

At this stage there are no public examples of multi item (on one page) carousels, but it is possible and I am currently working on a multi item carousel. I added margin and padding to achieve 15 thumbnails on 1 page.

:-)

Comment: i tried using padding at the time but could not make something work

Answer (score 0):

There is a coverflow plugin available not exactly same but similar. Check the demo here:

http://twomonkeys.com.ar/lab/cover/

You can get the source code here:

https://github.com/elmasse/Ext.ux.Cover

Comment: thank you but it is not the effect i want to obtain. It seems so simple but still could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use set itemLength property of Carousel,

```
Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
        fullscreen: true,
         itemLength: 250, // **you can change value as you want**
        defaults: {
            styleHtmlContent: true
        }, 
        items: [
            {
                html: 'item1',
                style: 'background-color:red;'
            }, {
                html: 'item2',
                style: 'background-color:white;'
            }, {
                html: 'item3',
                style: 'background-color:gray;'
            }, {
                html: 'item4',
                style: 'background-color:blue;'
            }, {
                html: 'item5',
                style: 'background-color:yellow;'
            }
        ] 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post where they explain it:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-the-leap-motion-controller-with-sencha-touch/

They used this in their code:

```
itemLength: browserWidth * 0.8.
```